# Submit Page with just Code Behind Using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest

I am creating a callback page that receives info from a payment gateway and then updates a database. I then want it to 'submit' itself automatically to a 'thank you' page, passing the order number as a hidden field.

I have looked at httpwebrequest, but I can't see with this solution how it will 'post itself' if that's the right way to put it.

Any help on ho to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why can't the callback page be the thank-you page?

Comment: Why not have the callbacked page just redirect to another page that does the thank you, or as blzm mentioned, the callback page can print the thank you.

Comment: the callback page is called by the payment gateway so it still under it's domain and ssl. Having the second page allows more flexibility. I could redirect, but then I would have to include query string parameters which I'd rather not do. But I'm open to any suggestions!

Comment: @ComfortablyNumb, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567882/submit-page-with-just-code-behind-using-c/7567935#7567935) doesn't need query string parameters if you just make a POST form instead of a GET form (which I think it does currently, depending on the browser defaults).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, why not using that **receive page** to also show what you need and save the trouble to have one more page?

If you still want to have  a 2nd page just to show the result, at the end of the processing you can write:

```
Session["job-id"] = "12345679";
Response.Redirect("my2ndpage.aspx");
```

in that 2nd Page, you simply assign the `session` text to the control you will have

```
HiddenField1.Value = Session["job-id"].ToString();
```

Comment: The reason for the second page is that it's not under the control of the payment gateway which makes life generally easier. The first page will be basically on a different domain as it's called by the payment gateway (although we host it).

Answer (score 3):

If the callback page is regular ASP.NET you could do a server-side `Response.Redirect` or `Server.Execute`.

If not you can do a client-side post in javascript:

```
<form action="yourThankYouUrl.aspx">
    <input type="hidden" name="callbackValue" value="yourCallbackValue" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.forms[0].submit();
</script>
```